# Fail to launch the Ipad simulator with Gradle

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, gradlew

After updating to Yosemite OSX 10, and to the latest Xcode 6, I ran the following command line to launch the iPad simulator as expected.

```
./gradlew launchIPadSimulator
```

Unfortunately, it still does not work and I get a:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':ios:launchIPadSimulator'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
....
```

How can I properly launch this iPad simulator?

Answer (score 0):

**Open XCode** qfter installation so that it can install the necessary components first. Just doing everything from the command line is not enough.

Now the iPad simulator is launched correctly.

I found out this solution after three days.